# PHP form text field to mysql based on selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to create sign up form, where it has multiple text field (name, email, phone, ..) and have multiple checkbox options.

I also created multiple tables in mysql database, one for each checkbox.
   My goal is to store values in text field to selected checkbox data table.

My question is how can I create if statement to look what checkbox is selected, so it will store input of text field to that table

**input.php**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chk1[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
<body>
<h2><font color="white">Welcome to Cars and Coffee</h2>
<p>Sign up to receive if you are interested in 
    receiving information from Cars and Coffee.</p>
<p>Please select at least one option</p>
<form name="newEntry" action="page.php" method="POST">
name<input type=text length=60 size=30 name="name"><br>
email<input type=text length=60 size=30 name="email"><br>
car<input type=text length=60 size=30 name="car"><br>
phone<input type=text length=60 size=30 name="phone"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" email="add" car="add" phone="add" >

</form>

<form action="page.php" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="cars_coffee">Cars  & Coffee<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="kentucky">Kentucky Derby Party<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="july">July 4th<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="labor">Labor Day<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="new_year">New Years Day<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="all" onClick="toggle(this)">Select All<br>

</form>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db", "pw");
mysql_select_db("db");
$qh = mysql_query("select * from  all_emails order by id desc");
if (@mysql_num_rows($qh)) { /* the if(@...) syntax makes PHP supress any
warnings that might come out of that function. */
        /* mysql_fetch_object(query handle);
         * returns an object whose contents are that of one rotw in the
database. */
        while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($qh)) {
                echo "
<p>
$obj->email<br>
$obj->name<br>
$obj->car<br>
$obj->phone<br>
<p>
<hr>
";
       }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db", "pw");
mysql_select_db("db");
mysql_query("insert into all_emails (name, email, car, phone) values ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['car']."', '".$_POST['phone']."' )");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; URL=./input.php">
</head>
</html>
```

Here is the if statement I am trying.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db", "pw");
mysql_select_db("db");

if( isset($_POST["cars_coffee"] ) ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cars_and_coffee (name, email, car, phone) values ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['car']‌​."', '".$_POST['phone']."' )");
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Record  is inserted";
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see an actual question posed, or a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: *"I also created multiple tables in mysql database, one for each checkbox."* - Seriously? Are you 100% sure you want to do this? You better rethink this, *seriously*.

Comment: @Zak I just editted, basically I am looking how I can use if statement to check what checkbox selected

Comment: @Fred-ii- you might be right, but my goal is to make goal specific table to get all the emails and send out email to them.

Comment: First of all all the name must be same like name='MT' and  the values must be different for individual check box like <input name='MT' value='value1' />  <input name='MT' value='value2' />. In case if you want multiple values to be check then must use array in name like <input name='MT[]' value='value1' />  <input name='MT[]' value='value2' />. Make sure you concentrate on name='MT' and name = 'MT[]'

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari can you please check my edit. My if statement also doesnt work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi use the following code :

NOTE : I highly suggest you to use mysqli or PDO. mysql functions are deprecated and are obsolate.

Please sanitize or safe cast your data before inserting into your database.

Also NOTE: In form I am redirecting to the same form page. Please use the appropriate php file name or routing path.

db_connect.php

```
$host       =   'localhost';
$user       =   'root';
$password   =   'root';
$database   =   'skerp';


$connection_error   =   'Sorry!!! We are experiencing problems with the database settings';

$link   =   mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or DIE($connection_error);
```

The following is the implementation

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   include_once ('db_connection.php');

   if(in_array('cars_coffee', $_POST['chk'])){
        $emails =   mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO all_emails (name, email, car, phone) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['car']."', '".$_POST['phone']."' )");
   }else{
    //If it fails then put the condition here or you may skip else part
      echo 'Not Exists';
   }

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="cars_coffee">Cars  & Coffee<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="kentucky">Kentucky Derby Party<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="july">July 4th<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="labor">Labor Day<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="new_year">New Years Day<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="all" onClick="toggle(this)">Select All<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!

Comment: I really appreciate for taking time and helping! 1) where in above code, its connecting my mysql database? 2) I am assuming you left text fields out by purpose. Because the values in text field is what I want to be added to my table

Comment: @mtkilic, I would like to suggest you to make a db_connect.php or with similar file name and require_once or include_once on top of the above file. Ya I have not done any connection, but you can put in the above condition inside if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ //Connect to your database }

Comment: I did this, I think this should work? https://gist.github.com/mtkilic/d1a17321d0a737ddc400bacb1b98a082

Comment: @mtkilic Yes it will work, can you please use the updated code as its more appropriate. And I highly suggest you to sanitize your data before inserting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works great!!

Comment: @mtkilic I am glad that it helped you. But I highly suggest you again to sanitize your data and use mysqli or PDO. Happy coding!

Comment: I am looking into mysqli, I hope its not to difficult to convert this to mysqli, because I am not php developer, I am doing work, for a friend

Comment: @mtkilic. Its same as mysql but few minor tweakings in their syntax. As per my idea you wont find much difficulty in learning. Hope this link helps you http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php Please dont get crazy by seeing that page. It's just a list of all the mysqli functions.

Comment: Truly appreciated for all of your helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isset method to check if a checkbox was selected.

```
if ( isset ( $_POST ["cars_coffee"] ) )
{
    // do something
}    
if ( isset ( $_POST ["kentucky"] ) )
{
    // do something else
}
...
```

Comment: is this what I do inside if to store text field to cars_coffee table? `$sq = "INSERT INTO cars_coffee (name, email, car, phone) values ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['car']."', '".$_POST['phone']."' )");`

Comment: I am not that strong in SQL but I think you are using too many quotes. Try this: `$sq = "INSERT INTO cars_coffee ( name, email, car, phone ) values ( $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['car']‌, $_POST['phone'] )";`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a slight problem with your logic because you are using checkboxes to retrieve data from the user. If you want the user to only select one checkbox, use a radio button. That will make them unable to select multiple. If I'm just not understanding you correctly and you really do want users to be able to select multiple boxes, then keep using checkboxes, but change the name attribute of each checkbox to be unique. Because right now, every checkbox has the same name, so it is going to read only the last checkbox that they checked.

The logic would go something like this if you continued using checkboxes and gave each checkbox a unique name:

```
$sql = '';
// make sure that the checkbox is set
if(isset($_POST['kentucky_checkbox'])){
{
   $sql += 'INSERT INTO kentucky VALUES ...;';
}
if(isset($_POST['labor_checkbox'])){
{
   $sql += 'INSERT INTO labor VALUES ...;';
}

etc.

...

// execute $sql
```

The logic would go something like this if you used radio buttons:

```
// make sure that the variable is set
if(isset($_POST['chk[]'])){
{
   // check what the value is
   switch ($_POST['chk[]']) {
      case 'option1':
         // set the table
         $table = 'table1';
         break;
      case 'option2':
         $table = 'table2';
         break;
      case 'option3':
         $table = 'table3';
         break;
   }
}

...

$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES ...';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but I do want user to be able to select more than, if they like. This means they will only get emails from selected checkboxes